# What’s the minimum sugar to egg white ratio in Swiss buttercream?

Tags: sugar, meringue, frosting, ratio

A Swiss meringue buttercream is a buttercream based on a sugar and egg white mix that is first heated and then whipped. The average recipes I could find use roughly one part egg white to two parts of sugar<sup>[1](https://www.indulgewithmimi.com/the-best-swiss-meringue-buttercream-for-macarons-cakes-321-ratio/)</sup>, some a bit more, some less<sup>[2](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2017/05/swiss-meringue-buttercream-frosting-recipe.html)</sup>.

I would like to reduce the sugar, but of course the sugar is not used just as sweetener, but is critical for the stability and texture of the meringue. So:

> What’s the minimum amount of sugar or lowest sugar-to-egg ratio needed for a Swiss meringue buttercream?

Two side notes:

- As [egg sizes definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_egg_sizes) differ and we’re talking ratios, please either use weight or state the egg size and the locale in your answer.
- This question is not about the butter to meringue ratio. I realize that the amount of butter will influence the stability of the buttercream.

Comment: I doubt you can separate the effect of the butter (i.e. I suspect the answer would be a function of butter content, considering the limiting cases). I wouldn't mind being proved wrong though, and I think the question is interesting (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Sugar is used to dissolve the egg whites and the protein film on the surface of the air bubbles ([source](https://www.finecooking.com/article/how-fragile-egg-white-foams-are-transformed-into-firm-airy-meringues#:%7E:text=Besides%20adding%20sweetness%2C%20sugar%20helps,and%20tightening%20up%20too%20fast.)).

Looking at [meringue ratio recommendations](https://whatscookingamerica.net/Eggs/perfectmeringue.htm), here is what I found.

> By varying the amount of sugar in the final mix, you control how hard or soft the final meringue will be.  As a general rule, add a **total of 1/4 cup of granulated or superfine sugar for each egg white.  Do not make meringues that have less than 2 tablespoons of sugar per egg white**. If you use any less, the foam will not set and the meringue will shrink.